# Problems with saving filled form in pdf

Tags: pdf, evince

I am filling out [1040 tax form](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1040.pdf) in evince.

1. Every time I try to save my input by
   ctrl+s, I am asked to "save as" in a
   dialog box. Is it possible to save to
   the current file without having the dialog box popping out each time?
2. On right middle of the first page,
   there is a box following “Add
   numbers on lines above". I enter a
   number and try to save it, but after
   answering the same "save as" dialog
   box as above, evince exists
   unexpectedly, and after I reopen the
   file, the input to that box is gone.
   If I try to print to file, the
   number in the box is kept, but the
   file no longer has fillable forms.
   So I was wondering why this happens?
   Is there a way to save the input to
   that box without losing the forms?

Thanks and regards!

P.S. My evince version is Document Viewer 2.32.0 Using poppler/cairo (0.14.3). My OS is Ubuntu 10.10

---

**ADDED**: I just found that I have to make the color of the input change from black to blue, before saving the pdf file, so that the saving is normal as usual and the pdf will not close itself unexpectedly. Is this the same thing that happens for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to save to the current file without having the dialog box popping out each time

No, apparently not.  I think this is because evince is biased towards viewing documents (and maybe saving a local copy of them) not editing.  You could [file a bug](http://pad.lv/fb/u/evince).

> On right middle of the first page, there is a box following “Add numbers on lines above". I enter a number and try to save it, but after answering the same "save as" dialog box as above, evince exists unexpectedly, and after I reopen the file, the input to that box is gone.

This works for me in natty, Ubuntu 11.04, so I guess this is a bug that has since been fixed.

Comment: Thanks! For the 2nd part, is there a solution for my 10.10?

Comment: I was wondering if your 11.04 the formal release, or some test version? Did you upgrade from 10.10 to 11.04, or reinstall 11.04, and which way do you recommend? Thanks!

Comment: I just found that I have to make the color of the input change from black to blue, before saving the pdf file, so that the saving is normal as usual and the pdf will not close itself unexpectedly. Is this the same thing that happens in evince of 11.04 for you?

Comment: @Tim I [upgraded to the Natty beta](http://www.ubuntu.com/testing/natty/beta) pretty much as shown in those instructions.  Bear in mind that it really is still a beta and you may encounter some bugs.  If you have enough disk space I would think about doing a separate dual-boot installation.

Comment: Apparently [both Maverick and Natty have evince 2.32.0](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=evince), but [natty has poppler 0.16](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=poppler), so I'm not sure if upgrading a single package will help.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "have to make the color change".  When I fill in the form, what I type just comes out blue without me taking any special action.

Comment: There is a feature request for 1) upstream at https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evince/-/issues/1281